# Why is Star Lord's species listed as Terran in this promo?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

This promo poster for Guardians of the Galaxy <strike>sequel ... video game</strike> ride has a profile of Star Lord that lists his **species** as Terran.

[image: GoG2 poster]

This isn't quite right -- one might say it's only 50% right. Or does species classification work differently in the Marvel Cinematic Universe? Note: I haven't <strike>seen GoG2 or played the game or</strike>  gone on the ride so I don't know if this is an error, a spoiler, or something else.

Comment: Mission: Breakout is a ride at Disney, not a game.

Comment: Surely it's an **anti**-spoiler? As in, it's intended to **not** spoil a plot point from the movie, which people viewing that poster may not have seen yet.

Answer (score 8):

The notation is a play off the sequence in the movie (and used extensively in the trailers ahead of the film's release) where Quill and the rest of the future Guardians of the Galaxy are being booked into custody by the Xandarians and the Nova Corps is reviewing the records on each of the suspects. At the time, as far as the Xandarians know, Quill is Terran, though they don't yet know that he is not (language warning):

> "100 percent a dick."

[image: Peter Quill booking image]

Comment: Is this image too offensive? Does it need a tag?

Comment: The booking scanner lists his "Origin" as Terran, which is factually correct. But origin is not the same as species.

Comment: "Terran" is a funny name for a *species*. A man and a goldfish and an oak tree would all "Terran", wouldn't they?

Comment: Using _Terran_ as an alias for _Human_ is a pretty common Sci-Fi trope.

Answer (score 2):

To the extent that the notion of a species is defined by the *[biological species concept](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/side_0_0/biospecies_01)*, two organisms belong to the same species exactly if they can and do interbreed.  While Star Lord's parents did not come from the same planet, their offspring is a fully functional organism.  Thus, despite the real-world of absurdity of two aliens belonging to the same breeding species, Star Lord's parents evidently are of the same species.  Referring to the species as "Terran" might be somewhat confusing to someone who did not know that Earthling humans could interbreed with aliens, but it otherwise a perfectly reasonable name for the transplanetary species.

Comment: Star Lord is kinda dysfunctional. :)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly because he is born of two humans, probably.

He's mother is a human being, his father is biologically a human being, it comes natural that he is a human being himself, no?

Comment: His father is human?

Comment: @RoboKaren as I wrote, "biologically". Ok, it's the Marvel-verse where everything is genetically possible, but from the movies we know that Ego formed a human body for himself to visit Earth. I guess he replicated human biology...